# Android Studio 3.5 - Installing Wear app on phone

Tags: android, wear-os

Smartphone: Galaxy S5 (Android 6.0.1 - not rooted)
Watch: Moto 360 1st gen (Android 6.0.1)

Signed app (apk) cannot be installed on Galaxy S5, so it cannot be used on the watch either.
It just says, "X App not installed" (after 3 seconds "Installing...)

On the wear emulator the app runs flawlessly.
The structure on the left is:
app
- manifest
- java
- java (generated)
- res
- res (generated)
Gradle Scripts
- build.gradle (project)
- build.gradle (module: app)
- gradle-wrapper.properties
- proguard-rules.pro
- gradle.properties
- settings.gradle
- local.properties

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.username.appname">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />
        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Colors" />
        <activity android:name=".ConfirmAction" />
        <activity android:name=".TriggerOnResume" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
        {
            compileSdkVersion 27
            defaultConfig
                    {
                        applicationId "com.example.username.appname"
                        minSdkVersion 23
                        targetSdkVersion 27
                        versionCode 1
                        versionName "1.0"
                    }
            buildTypes
                    {
                        release
                                {
                                    minifyEnabled false
                                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                                }
                    }
            buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        }
dependencies
        {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
            implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.1'
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
            implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
            implementation 'com.android.support:wear:27.1.1'
            compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.3.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        }
```

Since both devices (smartphone and watch) have the same android version,
I expect that the apk will be installed on the smartphone and after that automatically on the watch.

Any help will be apreciated!

Comment: For Android Wear 1.x the wearable app was installed via the phone. For Android Wear 2.x the wearable app must be installed directly on the wearable device. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hello, Inside of the Moto 360 settings (under version), it says "Android Wear 1.4.0" and Android OS 6.0.1.